# "can" for referring to the future

Tags: modal-verbs

1. You/one **can** get very nasty skin diseases from bathing in dirty water.

I know this is a generally true sentence. But could it refer exclusively to the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it can't refer *exclusively* to the future; it's a generalisation. It can happen to anyone, and it could happen to you in the future if you're not careful.

Comment: You used "could" but can I use "can" in: *it **can** happen to you in the future if you're not careful.*?

Comment: It wouldn't be very idiomatic.

Comment: Is the subject "you" in: *it could happen to **you** in the future if **you**'re not careful.* a specific subject, not just anyone?

Comment: _You_ can be the equivalent of _one_, as you used it in your original sentence, or it can be thought of as a personal address to the reader. I used that sense to demonstrate the reference to the future that you asked about.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any skin diseases now but you can get some in the future if you carry on bathing in dirty water. *Can* means it's possible, *will* stresses it's inevitable.